# Getting first day of the month, is outputting the wrong first day of the month

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to display the first day of the month in 'day of the week' format.
For example, The below code should select the month of August and say the day of the week 01 falls on which is Thursday, but for some reason, the below code outputs Friday which is wrong, on some months such as May it correctly says Wednesday.

```
$monthNumber = 3;
$base = strtotime(date('Y-m',time()) . '-01 00:00:01');
$dateTest = date("Ym" . 1, strtotime($monthNumber . " month", $base));
$unixTimestamp = strtotime($dateTest, $base);
echo date("l", $unixTimestamp);
```

Does anyone have any ideas to make it show the correct day?

$base fixes a bug with it not showing the correct month.

Comment: Shouldn't ```$monthNumber = 8``` if you're targeting August?

Comment: @Woodrow the way it works is $monthNumber is the number of months that added to the current month. The normal prefix for line 3 is strtotime("3 month", $base) the 3 could be -2 taking 2 months away from the current month

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And why won't you use the dateTime?

```
echo (new \DateTime('first day of august 2019'))->format('l');
```

Read more about [Relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use date() at first:

```
$base = date('Y-m',time()) . '-01 00:00:00';
```

And dont have to set the first second :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the day of the week falling on the first day of any month you can use the prefix `first day of` e.g.

```
echo (new \DateTime('first day of August'))->format('l');
```

This will show correctly Thursday for August 2019.

If you want to do it dynamically using numbers for months, you can create a dummy date like you were trying to do.

```
$timeString = sprintf('01.%02d.%04d', 8, 2019); // replace the numbers with your variables
echo (new \DateTime($timeString))->format('l');
```